# How do I print or call 1 return value from a function who takes multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a small video game where a player fights a monster. In it, I created a object "player", who uses a method called stats to return the players HP and Balance numbers. Dwarf will be my new object for now, as I will add other types later, and i'm trying to get document to write down the players stats, except in this case, individually. For now i'm using the player panel as a view to see how javascript will print the code, but later, I want to use specific div boxs to put in the players HP and Balance in 2 seperate fields. The problem i'm coming across is I can get the javascript code to print both variables together, but I cannot seem to call 1 or the other individually. Is there a way to do this? Also just for reference, when it prints the first line, it adds a coma, EX: 100, 250. Is there a way to remove that? Although I don't think it will be a issue if I get my first problem solved.

So how can I tell javascript that I only want to pull HP and write that.. or only pull Balance and write that? I tried to use indexing but that did not work.

```
var player = {
    stats: function (hp, balance){
        this.hp = hp;
        this.balance = balance;
        return [hp, balance]
    }   
}

var dwarf = Object.create(player);

document.getElementById("playerpanel").innerHTML += dwarf.stats(100, 250)
document.getElementById("playerpanel").innerHTML += dwarf.stats[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object, e.g.:

```
return {hp: hp, balance: balance};
```

Then pull just that property of the returned object:

```
//this executes the function and stores the returned object
var theCall = dwarf.stats(100, 250);

//this pulls the assigned property by name "balance"
document.getElementById("playerpanel").innerHTML += theCall.balance;
```

Answer (score 0):

`stats` should probably not be a function, rather a nested object.

```
var Player = {
    stats: {
        hp: 0,
        balance: 0
    }
}
...
dwarf.stats.hp = 100;
console.log(dwarf.stats.hp); // 100
console.log(dward.stats); // { hp: 100, balance: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a object containing both variables. You can then refer to the individual fields using their field names `hp` and `balance`, see below:

```js
var player = {
  stats: function(hp, balance) {
    this.hp = hp;
    this.balance = balance;
    return {
      hp, balance
    }
  }
}

var dwarf = Object.create(player);

document.getElementById("playerpanel").innerHTML += dwarf.stats(100, 250).hp
document.getElementById("playerpanel").innerHTML += ','+dwarf.stats(100, 250).balance
```

```html
<div id="playerpanel"></div>
```